# Optimality conditions - necessary vs sufficient

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

For a convex optimization problem, the first-order **necessary condition** says that at an optimum, the gradient is equal to zero.

$\triangledown L(w*) = 0 $

The second-order **sufficient condition** ensures that the optimum is a
minimum (not a maximum or saddle-point) using the Hessian matrix, which is the matrix of second derivatives:

$H(w*) := \dfrac{\partial^2L(w*)}{\partial w \partial w^T}$

is positive semi-definite. The Hessian is also related to the convexity of a function: a twice differentiable function is convex if and only if the Hessian is positive semi-definite at all points.

What is the difference between a necessary and a sufficient condition ? The definition of **necessary** in this context is clear to me since we need the gradient at the optimum to be equal to zero. What then, is the **sufficient** condition about ? Is the problem still convex if the **sufficient** condition is not satisfied ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A condition is necessary if it has to be true for some other statement to be true. In this case, the gradient *has* to be zero for the point $w^*$ to be a minimum. A condition is sufficient if that condition being true is enough to conclude that some other condition is true as well. In this case, if a site with gradient $0$ has a positive semi-definite Hessian, it has to be a minimum.

The necessary gradient condition is weakened by the fact that a site with gradient $0$ could also be a saddle point. We could say that it's a sufficient condition for concluding that the site is either an optimum or a saddle, though.

For the Hessian condition, note that it's only sufficient if we know that the site in question has gradient $0$. Knowing that a Hessian is positive semi-definite is a necessary condition for a site to be a minimum, but not a sufficient one: just think about any point on a convex parabola for a counterexample!

Comment: so if I have (1) necessary and (2) sufficient, 

- then proving (2) means that (1) also holds
- but proving (1) does not mean that (2) holds ?

Comment: Yes, if you show that the sufficient conditions hold, then the necessary conditions must also hold. In your case here, to show that something is unequivocally a minimum, you need to prove both that the gradient and the Hessian conditions hold though, as the Hessian condition is only sufficient under the conditions specified in my last paragraph.